# Linux developement towards iOS4-like touch-screen tablet

Tags: linux, user-interface, ios4

Is there any project or effort in the Linux community trying to develop something similar to Apple's iPad or iOS4? Or it is trivial to emulate the same touch-screen experience with Linux? I ask this question because I found iPad or iPhone UI experience is very friendly to young children and if possible could there be some linux-based tablet that targets children for education purpose. I tried Android on phone but it is far behind iphone. Simple example is to give an Android phone to a child, he/she may not know what to do but give a iphone to a child, she could immediately open an application and start playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Got one at least:

Gestures with multitouch in Ubuntu 10.10
http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/455